# Visual Studio C# if / else syntax error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, if-statement

I have a problem with my if/else code :/

```
private void btn_Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbtn_Bitcoin = checked)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/btc/sek");
    }

    else
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/ltc/sek");
    }
}
```

if `(rbtn_Bitcoin = checked)` after this statement I get three errors, "Syntax error, '(' expected" and two ") expected"

Comment: `if (rbtn_Bitcoin = checked)` -> `if (rbtn_Bitcoin == checked)`

Comment: See [=](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) and [==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)

Comment: Also, `checked` is a keyword.

Comment: You may accept the answer instead of updating(and making the question title confusing) the question!

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two errors:

- `checked` is a reserved keyword. Therefore you cannot use it as a name of a variable
- The other problem is that you use `=` which is the assignment operator and not the `==` which is the operator for equality comparison

Answer (score 2):

[`=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) is assignment operator. [`==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) is equality operator.

I assume you want to get your radio button is checked or not, you can use [`RadioButton.Checked` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control is checked.

```
if (rbtn_Bitcoin.Checked)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/btc/sek");
}
else
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/ltc/sek");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Double the `=` and use `checked` property:

```
private void btn_Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbtn_Bitcoin.Checked == true) <<-- == instead of =
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/btc/sek");
    }

    else
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/ltc/sek");
    }
}
```

Also `checked` is a reserved word, you can't use that this way. if you want to check whether the radio button is checked, use the `Checked` property.

You can also omit the `== true` part:

```
if (rbtn_Bitcoin.Checked) 
{
}
```

Comment: I still get the "Syntax error, '(' expected" and the two ") expected"

Comment: Use another variable name for 'checked', that's a reserved word.

Comment: `checked` is a reserved keyword. The answer should point this out.

Comment: okey well it's been a while since I last used C# but any names I could use? :s It's a radiobutton incase you didn't get that already

Comment: please tell, if this is wpf/asp.net/ anything else

Answer (score 1):

Assuming rbtn_Bitcoin is a radio button:

```
private void btn_Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbtn_Bitcoin.Checked)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/btc/sek");
    }

    else
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/ltc/sek");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The question is already answered.**

But if   `rbtn_Bitcoin`     is a `radio button` then you can use the following code directly without any comparison using `==` sign

```
private void btn_Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbtn_Bitcoin.IsChecked)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/btc/sek");
    }

    else
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://preev.com/ltc/sek");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `IsChecked` property of [`RadioButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx) class. It is [`Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Comment: There is IsChecked property, I checked the property in visual studio, WPF.

Comment: Who said this is about WPF?

Comment: Whatever, there is a property which tells whether radio button is checked, we should use it.